# Location filter in tweepy stream

Tags: python, stream, tweepy

I'm using `tweepy` stream for getting tweets from location *"CHENNAI"* but I'm getting `406 error`, can any one resolve it

```
Chennai= [80.237617, 13.067439 ,70.21565,7.01023]
auth = OAuthHandler(ckey, csecret)
auth.set_access_token(atoken, asecret)
twitterStream = Stream(auth, listener())
twitterStream.filter(locations = Chennai)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with the following
GEOBOX_GERMANY = [5.0770049095, 47.2982950435, 15.0403900146, 54.9039819757]

Comment: Yeah, it worked but I want to know why it isn't not working for chennai

Comment: Then it's clear there is no problem with the code right?? It is not relevant posting the code,u might have asked, are there any location limits by Twitter across the world..

Comment: Yeah, Thanks .. but do u know anything about twitter location limits, please share as i'm unable to find it